Does the following graph necessarily indicate a memory leak?
Implemented batch jobs using Spring Batch. However, I encountered OOM during the batch operation, and the heap memory graph looks like this.

There are also memory snapshots.

@Tasklet
class SynchronizeStudentsTasklet(
    private val customStudentRepository: CustomStudentRepository,
    private val studentClient: StudentClient,
    private val lectureClient: LectureClient,
) : ItemTasklet<Mono<Student>> {
    private val logger = getLogger()
    private val years = (2018..Year.now().value).toList()
    private var number = 100000
    private var index = 0

    override fun read(): Mono<Student>? =
        years.getOrNull(index)
            ?.let { year ->
                if (number >= 102000) {
                    index += 1
                    number = 100000
                }

                "$year${number++}"
            }
            ?.let {
                studentClient.getStudentByNumber(it)
                    .flatMap { student ->
                            Mono.zip(
                                lectureClient.getAppliedLectureIdsByStudentNumber(it)
                                    .collectList(),
                                lectureClient.getPreAppliedLectureIdsByStudentNumber(it)
                                    .collectList()
                            ).map { (appliedLectureIds, preAppliedLectureIds) ->
                                student.copy(
                                    appliedLectureIds = appliedLectureIds.toHashSet(),
                                    preAppliedLectureIds = preAppliedLectureIds.toHashSet()
                                )
                            }
                    }
            }

    override fun write(chunk: Chunk<out Mono<Student>>) {
        Flux.concat(chunk.items)
            .flatMap { customStudentRepository.upsert(it) }
            .doOnNext { logger.info { it } }
            .collectList()
            .block()
    }
}

Batch operations use chunk-based batching, and read() makes 6 HTTP requests (concurrency enforced, WebClient).
Looking at this, can we be sure that the cause of OOM is a memory leak?

Using netty.leakDetection.level=advanced resulted in the message LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before garbage collection. However, we did not use low-level ByteBuf, only WebClient.
We confirmed that Full GC was performed several times just before OOM.


The graph does look very much like a memory leak to me.  (What's important is not the high points, but the low points: they rise continuously, showing that after each GC, more heap memory is retained.)  But I'm afraid I don't know WebFlux or Netty, so I can't say why that's happening, whether there's a problem in your code, or how you might investigate it further.  (However, you do seem to be asking the right questions and using the right tools, so I hope you can get an answer.)
